# What is the proper way to use ids in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I need to use most of my child qml childrens in parent qml so using aliasing i am doing it now but some how i am not ok that calling **login.help.visible** too many dots. could some one give me best solution for this.

**here is my code**

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle{
        anchors.fill: parent
        Widget{
            id: login
        }
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: login.help.visible = false
            onEntered: {
                login.help.visible = true
                login.progress.visible = true
                ogin.pwd.visible = true
            }
            onExited: {
                login.help.visible = false
                login.progress.visible = false
                ogin.pwd.visible = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Widget.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Item {
    id: newid
    property alias help: helpid
    property alias progress: ploder
    property alias username: name
    property alias password: pwd
    Help{
        id: helpid
    }
    TextCustom{
        id: name
    }
    TextCustom{
        id: pwd
    }
    progressLoader{
        id: ploder
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, once I define a new `Component`, I use to encapsulate its children, logic and properties by hiding everything to the users, while I expose the properties that are freely modifiable (even the ones that belong to the children of my component) by means of its properties (aka the `property` keyword, correctly bound to the target properties of the component or of its children).

This way, the children of my component are nicely isolated from the users of the component itself.

It follows an example:

```
// MyComponent.qml

Item {
    property alias B: firstChild.B

    Item {
        id: firstChild
        property int A: 0 // this is hidden to the users of MyComponent...
        property int B: 0 // ... this is not, indeed
    }
}

// AnotherComponent.qml

// the outer Component has the following child
MyComponent {
    B: 3 // directly modifies the property B of firstChild in MyComponent
}
```

Comment: but to access children of my component we have  many dots rights. like id.propertyname.focus

Comment: added a short example, let me know if it's helpful to fully understand what I'm saying

Comment: for suppose if i have 10 childrens and each one having 10 properties in MyComponent.qml if i want expose all out do i need to create 10*10= 100 properties.

Comment: Well, that's a possible solution, I like it for it isolates the parts of the component. Can I ask you why do you have so many properties to expose? I mean, if you want to expose from the children properties like `x`, `y`, `width`, and so on, you are probably doing something wrong, for the real need is having different components, and it doesn't make much sense to create a bigger one, fully configurable down to each children, letting the user almost defining a completely different component regarding the one you decided to offer him. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: Ok fine, this is the only way to do this. cant we do this without exposing properties of childrens?

Comment: This is the way I prefer, for it's safe. I guess someone else would suggest different approaches, there is no a most right way, you have to find the one with which you feel confident. :-)

Comment: Also, do not forget to close the question by accepting a response, if you find that one of them fits your needs. It will help newcomers and their future searches.